# Error close application to launch Android service

Tags: java, android

My application is composed of a service called **FirstService.Java**.

When the device connect want the service to start
But the service nai start of an error: close application

My this code:

**StartService.java**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;  
import android.content.Context;  
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class StartService extends BroadcastReceiver {
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         Toast.makeText(context, "Exemplo Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, FirstService.class);
                context.startService(serviceIntent);
            }

     }

}
```

The **Manifest.xml** have it

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.niceplace.liveslink"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-feature />


     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.niceplace.liveslink.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

         <activity
            android:name=".image"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="Imagem" >
        </activity>


         <service 
        android:name="com.niceplace.liveslink.FirstService"
        android:enabled="true"
         />

  <receiver android:name=".StartService">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   </intent-filter>
  </receiver>


    </application>



</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have managed to solve the problem, it was a line of my script that was looking for a GetCookie cookie

When you start the service it is no cookie! But if I enter the application he gets cookie!

```
 String uid = getCookie("www.liveslibk.com", "uid");
```

Thank you all who tried to help me!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to add the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission into your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: `      if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, FirstService.class);
                context.startService(serviceIntent);
            }`